# MVC multiple cascading dropdown filtering table using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, sorting

I would like to have multiple dropdowns that filter a the table on the same page. When you go to the page it displays a table when you select the first dropdown it narrows the data and updates the second dropdown.

Here is an example i'm working on [MVC Sort headers and Dropdown Ajax update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319037/mvc-sort-headers-and-dropdown-ajax-update)

I can get the cascading dropdowns working or I can get the table to update but I can't get both.

I am trying to use ajax so the page doesn't reload.

Any guidance or examples would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen your code, so can not tell exact problem. Here is how I see your solution. First add your second dropdown value to your filter method, it should have default value when not chosen.

```
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string id, 
                              string channelLocation, int secon_ddl = 0)
```

Then check if second is chosen, in this case is it for 0, and filter

```
    if(secon_ddl != 0)
    {
       //do whatever
    }
```

Add another method wich returns list of items to second method and invoke it when firts dropdown value changed. Best option is return value in JSON format.
Here is my code, i am updating subcategory list when category changed

```
('#category_list').change(function() {
    var cat_value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Product/GetSubCategory',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { category: cat_value },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                var list = $('#subCategory_list');
                list.html(""); // clear before appending new list
                list.append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(null).html("Chose"));
                $.each(data, function (i, subCat) {
                    list.append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(subCat.id).html(subCat.name));
                });
            }            
        }
    });
}
```

I am using jquery datatables, so updating table is simple

```
 ('#category_list, #subCategory_list').change(function(){
       table.draw();
 })
```

In your case this last code should be totally differnt. Just make sure that your filter mehtod recieves values of both dropdown lists, and its firing when one of dropdowns changed. Hope this helps you!!